# Did Ibn Abbas allow masturbation?

Tags: authenticity, masturbation

There's a famous news media here in my country that once posts an article about masturbation. It talked about masturbation is haram according to some scholars (and makruh according to some scholars, or allowed/mubah in some condition). The interesting part is that it says the following (translated to english):

"Ibn Abbas (Sahabah) allows masturbation because muslims back then do it when fighting in a war (far from family). Even Mujahid (a student of Ibn Abbas) said that Prophet Muhammad PBUH tolerate it at that time. Mujahid also said that masturbation is not good for health because : ..... "

---

Did they really said that? I also know that Ibn Abbas said that masturbation was better than zina.

Comment: Did the article mention a source? See [Musannaf Abdul Razzaq](https://ia802500.us.archive.org/14/items/waq15649/07_15655.pdf#page=390), page 390-391. I would say that the translation you have given is somewhat off, as their view is closer to considering it permitted for averting Zina.

Answer (score -1):

The Hadith of ibn abbas is collected by imam bayhaqi and he declared the hadith weak in Sunan Al Kubra Lil Bayhaqi .

Comment: It would be better if you shared the hadith quote